# Apache VFS resolveFile with regex

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

If I have a directory called `temp` with the following files:

```
a_file1.jpg
a_file2.jpg
b_file1.jpg
b_file2.jpg
```

It's possible to get all files like this:

```
VFS.getManager().resolveFile("temp").getChildren();
```

But, what I actually want to do is get `a_file1.jpg` and `a_file2.jpg`. Maybe like:

```
VFS.getManager().resolveFile("temp/a*").getChildren();
```

But this throws an exception:

```
org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not list the contents of "temp/a*" because it is not a folder.
```

So, does anyone know how to resolve a set of files based on a regex with VFS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`findFiles`](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileObject.html#findFiles%28org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSelector%29) method, with a [`FileFilterSelector`](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileFilterSelector.html).

You'll need to create your own `FileFilter` that `accept`s the files that match your desired regex.

Comment: Thanks Mat. Google found this page with a code sample:

http://wiki.apache.org/commons/VfsFaq